# How I can fix the next error on a ASN.1 notation file?

Tags: asn.1

I'm compiling the MMS syntax notation for ASN.1 and a Eclipse plugin shows me the next error: "Syntax error on token "ConfirmedServiceRequest", } expected". This's my code:

```
MMSpdu ::= CHOICE
{
    confirmed-RequestPDU            [0]     IMPLICIT Confirmed-RequestPDU,
    ...
}

Confirmed-RequestPDU ::= SEQUENCE
{
    invokeID                        Unsigned32,
    listOfModifier                  SEQUENCE OF Modifier OPTIONAL,
    ConfirmedServiceRequest,               ------ here is the error
    [79] CS-Request-Detail OPTIONAL
}
```

What's wrong? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the comma after ConfirmedServiceRequest is unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

It could be that it is expecting the elements in the SEQUENCE to all be named.  Add an element name for the last two items.  Older ASN.1 didn't require this, but it is required in the latest ASN.1 standards.